# how to create build steps in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to add build steps in an Eclipse project (Eclipse CDT Version: 3.8.0 on Debian).

For instance, when instructing Eclipse to build it would:

```
1- Run premake
2- Run make
```

You get the gist.

There's 0 tutorials on the subject and I looked everywhere... Is it because this feature doesn't exist? That's hard to believe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tutorial for Eclipse build :D
May be you want to build your project? Correct me if I am wrong.
As I know, Eclipse supports us to use *Ant build* to build/ execute the build step for projects (**not for Eclipse itself**) => build.xml
And If you really want to do some things else, i think create a bat file. and then execute it when start Eclipse is a suggestion.